# The app don´t work well with spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm begging with the framework spring and spring-security. To learn, I´m developing an app.
Up to now I have developped the app without spring-security, for validate to the user by way a login´s form. When the user introduce your username and password my app goes to the controller, to method "post" and it´s there where I validate your ids (username and password), I make use of the Validator class

Now I´ve introduced spring-security for get more security, but when user introduce your ids (username and password), the app never redirect to method post of the controller if no redirect to method get the whole time

Up next is the source code

The jsp file of form is:

```
...
<form:form name="f" commandName="usuario" action="j_spring_security_check" method="POST" >
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
                <td><form:errors path="errorUsuario" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
    <tbody>
             <tr>
                    <td><span id="letra">Usuario</span></td>
                    <td><form:input path="nombreUsuario" name='j_username' id="fondo-gris"/></td>
                 <td><form:errors path="nombreUsuario" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                  <td><span id="letra">Password</span></td>
                  <td><form:password path="clave" name='j_password' id="fondo-gris"/></td>
               <td><form:errors path="clave" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>   
                   <td colspan="3"><center><input id="botonInciar" type="submit" name="guardar" value="Iniciar Sesión"/></center></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
...
```

The controller of this page is:

```
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model modelo) throws Exception {

        logger.info("LogginController --> login: ha entrado en el método GET");

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        modelo.addAttribute("usuario", usuario);

        logger.info("LogginController --> login: los resultados del usuario son, userName: " + usuario.getNombreUsuario());

        return "index";
    }

    /**
     * Recoge los parámetros y redireccionamos donde necesitamos
     * @param usuario El usuario que intenta acceder al sistema
     * @param result Resultado del acceso
     * @param status Estado de lasesión
     * @return Retornamos la redirección a la página donde debe de ir tras la validación
     */
   @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String processSubmitLogin(@ModelAttribute("usuario") Usuario usuario, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    logger.info("LogginController --> processSubmitLogin: ha entrado en el método POST");

    UsuarioLoggin ul = new UsuarioLoggin(usuario, usuarioService);
    new LogginValidator().validate(ul, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "index";
        } else {
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/ok.htm";
        }
    }
...
```

The configuration file of spring-security is: securityApplicationContext.xml:

```
...
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/index"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
...
```

PS: Testing and testing.. I saw that If removed the label: "j_spring_security_check" of the jsp file, the app found as until now, but if I leave it when the user push for to send the data, the application is whole time in the method "get" of the controller

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security introduces a set of filters that will intercept certain requests. By default, Spring Security will intercept a request for `j_spring_security_check` and handle the authentication for you.

Because of this, you will never see Spring MVC handle the `POST` request that you are expecting for a couple reasons:

1. You are never `POST`ing to `/index` - From what I see above, the user will `GET` `/index` and submit the form to `j_spring_security_check`. There is never a `POST` to `/index`
2. You would never want to have Spring MVC handle the authentication request - This is the benefit of using a security framework; your MVC code does not have to handle authentication or authorization.

Instead of the above code, you will need to do the following:

1. Remove the `processSubmitLogin()` method from your MVC code as it is no longer needed.
2. Add any custom handling from `processSubmitLogin()` to your Spring Security configuration in order to have the same user experience.

`processSubmitLogin()` does 3 things: Actually authenticates the user (this is now done via Spring Security), forwards to `index` in case of errors and redirects to `ok.htm` on success. The last two are configured in Spring Security like the following:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/index"
        authentication-failure-url="index"
        default-target-url="/ok.htm"
        always-use-default-target="true"/>
</security:http>
```

The above configuration should match your custom login page when using Spring Security. See the [form-login namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login) for more information on the above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer me.
I don't understand everything that you write me, that is, when you say:
1. Remove the processSubmitLogin() method from your MVC code as it is no longer needed. What do you refer? Something is alike to this:

New jsp file

```
 ... 
   <form name="f" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post" >
       <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
          <tbody>
             <tr>
            <td><span id="letra">Usuario</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="fondo-gris"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
            <td><span id="letra">Password</span></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="fondo-gris"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>   
            <td colspan="3"><center><input id="botonInciar" type="submit" name="guardar" value="Iniciar Sesión"/></center></td>
         </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
     </form>
...
```

New controller .java

```
/**
     * Método que sirve para visualizar la página principal de la aplicación
     * @param modelo
     * @return Un String con el nombre de la página
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    //@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model modelo) throws Exception {
        //modelo.addAttribute("tituloUsuario", "Listado de Usuarios");

        logger.info("LogginController --> login: ha entrado en el método GET");

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        modelo.addAttribute("usuario", usuario);

        logger.info("LogginController --> login: los resultados del usuario son, userName: " + usuario.getNombreUsuario());

        //return "/principal/loguear";
        return "index";
    }
```

New spring-security: securityApplicationContext.xml:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/index"
                             default-target-url="/principal/usuarios/form.htm"
                             always-use-default-target="true"
                             authentication-failure-url="/index"/>

    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

If I do this, when user introduces wrong the data, the browser don´t display the information, ie, Incorrect Username/Password Combination

How do the data are displayed in the browser?

Thanks